# How create a result table with result group of the columns

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need make a group with result of 2 columns and separate by lines from name and columns from size.

**Example: Table Base**

```
Name             | Size | Item
Frankincense     | 5ml  | 1562
Frankincense     | 10ml | 1563
Frankincense     | 15ml | 1564
Geranium         | 5ml  | 1565
Geranium         | 10ml | 1566
Geranium         | 15ml | 1567
Ginger           | 5ml  | 1568
Ginger           | 10ml | 1569
Ginger           | 15ml | 1570
Grapefruit       | 5ml  | 1571
Grapefruit       | 10ml | 1572
Grapefruit       | 15ml | 1573
Lavender         | 5ml  | 1574
Lavender         | 10ml | 1575
Lavender         | 15ml | 1576
```

**Example: Table Result**

```
Name/Size    | 5ml  | 10ml | 15ml
Frankincense | 1562 | 1563 | 1564
Geranium     | 1565 | 1566 | 1567
Ginger       | 1568 | 1569 | 1570
Grapefruit   | 1571 | 1572 | 1573
Lavender     | 1574 | 1575 | 1576
```

I found something, but don't have the result yet. I need group the column size and made sure the result is correct.

```js
data = [['Frankincense','5ml','1562'],
['Frankincense','10ml','1563'],
['Frankincense','15ml','1564'],
['Geranium','5ml','1565'],
['Geranium','10ml','1566'],
['Geranium','15ml','1567'],
['Ginger','5ml','1568'],
['Ginger','10ml','1569'],
['Ginger','15ml','1570'],
['Grapefruit','5ml','1571'],
['Grapefruit','10ml','1572'],
['Grapefruit','15ml','1573'],
['Lavender','5ml','1574'],
['Lavender','10ml','1575'],
['Lavender','15ml','1576']]
data.sort()
var title = data.reduce(function(result, value) {
    if ( result.indexOf(value[1]) === -1 ) {
      result.push(value[1]);
    }
    return result;
}, []).map(function(group) {
    return group
});

var result = data.reduce(function(result, value) {
    if ( result.indexOf(value[0]) === -1 ) {
      result.push(value[0]);
    }
    return result;
}, []).map(function(group) {
    return [group,...data.filter(function(_el) {
          return _el[0] === group;
       }).map(function(_el) { return _el[2]; })]
});

title.unshift('Name/Size')

result.unshift(title)

result.forEach(item => console.log(item.join('\t| ')))
```

Comment: Are you trying to log a table to the console? If so, use `console.table` instead.

Comment: If the output is going to be displayed in a fixed-width font then padding with space characters is simple. If the output is for a web page just use a `<table>` element. If the output is for the console use `console.table()` as already mentioned.

Comment: Oh, thanks, I didn't know about that console.table(). So I just want to make the focus in the group by name/size.